# create function with array index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to create lot of functions that contain almost same pattern and coding.

Creating multiple function becomes more useful to use different purpose and pages for my project. For example:

```
    function cls(){
        $.ajax({  
            url:"crud/fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{cat:'cls'},
            success:function(data){
                $('#cls').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function stdt(){
        $.ajax({  
            url:"crud/fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{cat:'stdt'},
            success:function(data){
                $('#stdt').html(data);
            }
        });
    }


    function sec(){
    ......
    //same pattern
    }

    function pdl(){
    ......
    //same pattern
    }
```

I tried to contain these function in one function to reduce code that seems clean, easy for debugging and re-editing.

So I tried storing all desired function name in one array and create function using each index.

But I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: cls is not a function`. I have tried without using `window[cat]`. I think it is foolish way, but tried, hoping it can works. Please suggest how can I assign or create function using each array index value.

```
var menu = ["cls", "stdt", "sec", "pdl", "sub", "xsub", "cls_sub", "cls_xsub", "xam", "mrksch", "grdsch", "sclnfo"];
$.each(menu, function(i,cat){
    var ftch = window[cat];
    function ftch(){
        $.ajax({  
            url:"crud/fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{menu:cat},
            success:function(data){
                $('#"' + cat+ '"';).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: @FrankerZ, I'd tried this, but got same error `Uncaught TypeError: cls is not a function`

Comment: Shouldn't you create a single function and with `cat` as parameter and pass the relevant string while calling the function. That would be really clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a string in this code

```
var ftch = window[cat];
function ftch(){
```

I'm guessing you think this means create a function called cat on the window object, which you are then defining with `ftch`, however this simply gets the object stored at `window[cat]` (which will be undefined) and then tries to create another function called `ftch`.

To fix this, simply change your code to:

```
window[cat] = function(){
    $.ajax({  
        url:"crud/fetch.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{menu:cat},
        success:function(data){
            $('#"' + cat+ '"';).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use anonymous functions. Also, quick side note, you have a syntax error with `$('#"' + cat+ '"';)`:

```
var menu = ["cls", "stdt", "sec", "pdl", "sub", "xsub", "cls_sub", "cls_xsub", "xam", "mrksch", "grdsch", "sclnfo"];
$.each(menu, function(i,cat){
    window[cat] = function () {
        $.ajax({  
            url:"crud/fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{menu:cat},
            success:function(data){
                $('#' + cat).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Although, I would highly recommend that you create a custom variable/class, to avoid too much pollution to the global scope:

```
window.fetch = {};

var menu = ["cls", "stdt", "sec", "pdl", "sub", "xsub", "cls_sub", "cls_xsub", "xam", "mrksch", "grdsch", "sclnfo"];
$.each(menu, function(i,cat){
    window.fetch[cat] = function () {
        $.ajax({  
            url:"crud/fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{menu:cat},
            success:function(data){
                $('#"' + cat+ '"';).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can even make the above approach dynamic with a Proxy (This is just a demonstration, you should simply just create a function with a parameter):

```js
var fetchMenu = new Proxy({}, {
  get: function(obj, cat, val) {
    return () => {
      console.log('Lets load ' + cat);
    };
  }
});

var menu = ["cls", "stdt", "sec", "pdl", "sub", "xsub", "cls_sub", "cls_xsub", "xam", "mrksch", "grdsch", "sclnfo"];


fetchMenu.cls();
```

Although, this appears to be an X/Y issue. What's your reasoning for doing this? **Why not just create a function that takes a parameter for what to fetch?**

```
function fetchCat(cat) {
    $.ajax({  
        url:"crud/fetch.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{menu:cat},
        success:function(data){
            $('#' + cat).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Later on...you can do something as simple as:

```
$.each(menu, (i, cat) => fetchCat(cat));
```

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: No I mean can't OP create single function with a parameter and use that instead of creating multiple functions? It seems to defeat the whole point of functions.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the last code snippet @psinaught

Comment: @FrankerZ, last one seems great. Thanks ! Man !!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function using the window command

```
window(function_name,parameters);
```